# Google Calendar API Event color not set

Tags: json, google-calendar-api

Using following request the event is created like a charm but the color is not set. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
{
   "summary":", Meier, Test Musterfirma GmbH",
   "location":"Musterstrasse 8, 8000 Zurich",
   "description":"Test Musterfirma GmbH",
   "start":{
      "dateTime":"2016-03-31T11:00:00",
      "timeZone":"Europe/Zurich"
   },
   "end":{
      "dateTime":"2016-03-31T12:00:00",
      "timeZone":"Europe/Zurich"
   },
   "visibility":"private",
   "ColorId":"10",
   "transparency":"opaque"
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: "ColorId" to "colorId"?

Comment: @SwagBomb You made my day, thank you :)